# HTML + Load one html partial inside another html page using Jquery Load Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 HTML files

```
File 1. index.html
File 2. nav_bar.html
```

Here I am trying to load static page `nav_bar.html` into `index.html`

I tried one of the jquery `load` method - sample code of index.html. ie.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
       $("#nav_bar").load("nav_bar.html"); 
    });
</script>
```

Working fine with Firefox but Chrome does not response to load this file. I am not getting the way to resolve it. Note: Please avoid the use of iframe.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no reason that would not work in Chrome. What error did you get?

Comment: NO such error, it does not load that partial.

Comment: What about using HTML imports: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/

Comment: Only shows nav_bar.html on html page and tried .html as well

Comment: I think the cause is that you are opening the file (index.html) directly into the browser (chrome) and not using a server or apache or something like that?

Comment: Yes, I am opening the file directly from folder rather than any server or apache. May be I will try by installing wamp or any server to see the effect.

Comment: Yes, you need to run it on a webserver. Chrome is blocking the request because you are attempting to access the file system of the local machine.

Comment: Yes @RoryMcCrossan : Your are right. I tried to execute the same page in netbeans using default server. It is rendering the page perfectly. My bad to execute the page without server. Thanks a lot Guys ...

Answer (score 0):

Chrome enforces same origin policy. Read about it [here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)

Fetch html from server via ajax and load it as string.

Read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976046/jquery-load-function-form-in-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

For disabling same origin policy for chrome : Use [Stackoverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome)  or  [this](http://joshuamcginnis.com/2011/02/28/how-to-disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome/)

Comment: Will this change, may raise any security concern ?

Comment: yeah thats a concern , For other avialble options kindly see what are other workarounds , [link] (http://usamadar.com/2012/06/24/getting-around-browsers-same-origin-policy-sop-with-proxies-script-injection-jsonp-and-cors/ )  .. I think Dynamically Inject the ‘src’ of a <script> tag is a better option